# if $Y \in S_A$ for which $C (Y) \subsetneq C (A)$. Show that $S_A$ is infinite.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $p,n\geq 1$ and $A\in \mathcal{M}_p(\mathbb{R})$ and the set $S_A=\{X\in \mathcal{M}_p (\mathbb{R}):X^n=A\}$ and $C(A)=\{P\in GL_p(\mathbb{R}):AP=PA \}$. We suppose that $S_A = \bigcup _{X\in S_A} O(X)$, where $O(X) = \{PXP^{-1} : P\in C(A)\}$ is the orbit of $X$ for the action of $C (A)$ on $\mathcal{M}_{p}(\mathbb{R})$,  and this union of orbits is a finite union.

We assume that there exists $Y \in S_A$ for which $C (Y) \subsetneq C (A)$. Show that $S_A$ is infinite.

**my attempt**

Let $P \in C (A)\setminus C (Y)$. For all $\epsilon > 0$, $I_p + \epsilon P \in C (A)\setminus  C (Y) $ and for $\epsilon$ small enough $I_p +\epsilon P \in GL_p (\mathbb{R})$.
Can we say that for all the small enough $\epsilon > 0$ $(I_p + \epsilon P) Y (I_p + \epsilon P)^{−1}$ describe distinct elements of $S_A$ ?

Comment: You have assumed that $\cup_{X\in S_A}O(X)$ is a finite union and yet you want to show that $S_A$ is infinite. What do you mean?

Comment: that is, there exists a finite family of orbits, but perhaps an orbit will be of infinite cardinality.